# Problema con consultas preparadas dentro de while php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php8

Realizo mi primera consulta SQL de la tabla transferencias y todo me sale bien, realizo luego dentro del `while` de esa consulta, la consulta de mi tabla del saldo de los empleados y simplemente no me muestra nada, queda en blanco.

Esa misma consulta la ejecuto fuera del `while` y corre sin problema, incluso la tengo en una `function` pero  por ningún lado logro hacer que me corra dentro del `while`, tenía pensado guardar todo en un `array` y así hacer la consulta fuera del while, pero me parece que no es la mejor solución.

```
$consult = "SELECT  $Tabla_bancocreditar.banco, $Tabla_emple.nombre AS nom, $Tabla_emple.num_cedula, $Tabla_emple.num_telefono, $Tabla_emple.exonerado, $Tabla_emple.idtipo_empleados, $Tabla_emple.idtipo_pagos, $Tabla_pagos.idpagos, $Tabla_pagos.pagos, $Tabla_porcentaje.idporcentaje, $Tabla_tranfe.idtransferencias, $Tabla_tranfe.idpagos AS pagoaprobado, $Tabla_tranfe.cuenta, $Tabla_tranfe.pais_transferencia, $Tabla_tranfe.numtransferencias, $Tabla_tranfe.nombre, $Tabla_tranfe.cedula_trans, $Tabla_tranfe.montobolivares,
$Tabla_tranfe.tasadetal, $Tabla_tranfe.ganancia_emp, $Tabla_tranfe.iddepartamento, $Tabla_tranfe.idpais_acred, $Tabla_tranfe.recarg, $Tabla_tranfe.idpais, $Tabla_tranfe.tasamayor, $Tabla_tranfe.comisiones, $Tabla_tranfe.nombre_banco_acre, $Tabla_tranfe.idtipo_doc, $Tabla_tranfe.porcobrar, $Tabla_tranfe.totalp, $Tabla_tranfe.status_transf, $Tabla_tranfe.correo_trans, $Tabla_tranfe.comentario, $Tabla_tranfe.fecha_abono,  $Tabla_tranfe.fecha_cobro, $Tabla_tranfe.fecha_reg,
$Tabla_tranfe.idperfil_admin, $Tabla_tranfe.correo_servicio, $Tabla_tranfe.idtipo_plan, $Tabla_tranfe.idtipo_producto, $Tabla_tranfe.idtipo_servicios, $Tabla_tranfe.idbancod, $Tabla_tranfe.idtipo_cuenta_banco, $Tabla_tranfe.idservicio, $Tabla_tranfe.idbancoc
FROM $Tabla_tranfe INNER JOIN $Tabla_bancocreditar ON $Tabla_tranfe.idbancoc = $Tabla_bancocreditar.idbancoc  INNER JOIN $Tabla_emple ON $Tabla_tranfe.idempleados = $Tabla_emple.idempleados INNER JOIN $Tabla_pagos ON $Tabla_tranfe.idpagos = $Tabla_pagos.idpagos INNER JOIN $Tabla_porcentaje ON $Tabla_tranfe.idporcentaje = $Tabla_porcentaje.idporcentaje 
WHERE $Tabla_tranfe.cedula=? AND $Tabla_tranfe.num_cedula=? AND $Tabla_tranfe.recarg!=? AND $Tabla_tranfe.idrelacion!=? AND $Tabla_tranfe.idpagos=? AND $Tabla_tranfe.fecha_reg=? ORDER BY $Tabla_tranfe.idtransferencias ASC  LIMIT 0, 300";

$resultado=mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consult);
$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "ssiiis", $ced, $Empleados, $uno, $cero, $Tipo_t, $Fecha_cosut);
```

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)){
    
        $Exonerado = $exonerado;            
        $Idservicio_nuev = $idservicio;                 
        $Correo_serv = $correo_servicio;                
        $Correo_trans = $correo_trans;                      
        $Recarg = $recarg;              
        $Idpais_acred = $idpais_acred;  
        $Idtipo_cuentas = $idtipo_cuenta_banco;         
        $Idproduc = $idtipo_servicios;
        $Idserv = $idtipo_producto;
        $Idplan = $idtipo_plan;
        $Idperfil_admin = $idperfil_admin;
        $Idtipo_doc = $idtipo_doc;  
        $Num_telefono = $num_telefono;  
        $Pagoaprobado = $pagoaprobado;
        $Num_cedula = $num_cedula;
        $Idtransferencias = $idtransferencias;  
        $Bancoc = $banco;
        $Idbancoc = $idbancoc;      
        $Idbancod = $idbancod;
        $NomE = $nom;
        $Idtipo_pagos = $idtipo_pagos;  
        $Iddep = $iddepartamento;
        $Idpatransf = $pais_transferencia;  
        $Idpais = $idpais;      
        $Nombre =$nombre;
        $Idpag = $idpagos;
        $Pag = $pagos;
        $Idporcentaje = $idporcentaje;
        $Cuenta = $cuenta;
        $Numtransferencias = $numtransferencias;
        $Status_transf = $status_transf;                
        $Cedula=$cedula_trans;
        $Montobolivares = $montobolivares;
        $Tasadetal = $tasadetal;
        $Tasamayor = $tasamayor;
        $Comisiones = $comisiones;
        $Porcobrar = $porcobrar;
        $Totalp = $totalp;
        $Ganancia = $ganancia_emp;
        $Comentario = $comentario;
        $Reg_trans = $fecha_reg;
        $H_trans = $fecha_abono;                
        $Reg_cobro = $fecha_cobro;
        $Idtipo_emp = $idtipo_empleados;    
        $Nom_banco_acre = $nombre_banco_acre;

 $consult_pa = "SELECT saldo FROM $Tabla_saldo_emp  WHERE cedula=? AND num_cedula=? AND idpais=?";
$resultado_saldo=mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consult_pa);
$ok_n=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado_saldo, "ssi", $ced, $Num_cedula, $Idpatransf);
$ok_n=mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado_saldo);

if($ok_n==true){
    $ok_n=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado_saldo, $saldo_pais);   
    while ($resultado_saldo->fetch()) {
        
        
        echo "$saldo_pais bbbbbbb";
        
    }   
    mysqli_stmt_close($resultado_saldo);
}
```

Comment: El problema es que estas reutilizando la variable que usas para hacer el while ;)... usa una nueva variable y listo...

Comment: hola amigo e actualizado con la nueva consulta remplazando los la variable del while incluso  la del select de la segunda consulta completa a ver y sigue en blanco, al quitar la consulta todo normal e incluso si saco la consulta del otro while y le coloco los valores ps me hace la consulta sin problemas

Comment: no entiendo que es lo que esperas que pase, que no pasa.. no entra al while interno? o sea no te muestra esos echo? y estas seguro que los parametros estan bien?

Comment: ademas hay algo raro.. si esta dentro del while, lo estas ejecutando para todas las filas que trajiste.. si esta afuera, lo estas ejecutando solo para la ulitma.. que tratas de hacer?

Comment: ok estoy  diciendole que recorrar todas las finas de transferencias y  y me muestre los datos luego dentro de ese que seria el primer while le digo al otro, entra a la tabla de paises y con el numero de documento y el pais del empleado, muéstrame el saldo que tiene disponible este, eso seria lo que quiero que pase en el segundo while,  como lo que esta en el segundo while lo tenia en una funcion, lo agarra era con un return pero  como con la funcion no pasaba nada lo meti adentro del while directo a ver y tampoco, realizo un echo de los parametros que le envio esta todo bien por esa parte.

Comment: ok.. yo no entiendo tu problema.. alguien mas lo entendera.. pero no deberias directamente agregar esa informacion a tu primer query?

Comment: El principal problema aquí es que estás usando una herramienta de la cual ignoras un aspecto fundamental, por tanto haces un uso precario de la misma desperdiciando recursos. Me refiero a que las bases de datos **son relacionales**, esa es una de sus principales razones de ser, por tanto, no tiene sentido que ejecutes una consulta para luego, recorriendo las filas que te trae esa consulta ejecutes otra consulta `N` veces. Este puede ser un código costosísimo a nivel de recursos. Haz uso de la relacionalidad de la base de datos, escribiendo **una sola consulta** que te devuelva los datos.

Comment: Otra cosa, por si algún día necesitas ejecutar consultas preparadas de forma repetitiva (aquí no lo necesitas si construyes una sola consulta que te traiga todas las filas que requieres), **las consultas se preparan una sola vez, fuera del bucle**, no tiene sentido preparar una y otra vez la misma cosa. Si lo reflexionas, la consulta es fija, lo único que cambia son los valores, los cuáles sí debes vincular cada vez, dentro del bucle con `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`.

Comment: si tienes razon cedano, lo que pasa es que bueno me falto relacionar esa ultima tabla del saldo y por eso pensaba sacarla asi de esa forma pero bueno voy a relacionarla y hacer  todo en una consulta, de la mejor forma, gracias.